# How to sum differente source while adding the max date of a source to the others sources

Tags: sql-server, powerbi, dax

I am confronted with a big dilemma as I am having to figure out how to sum the below case:

[image]

---

Knowing that the expected result is to get the below total.

[image]

Your help is sincerely appreciated.

Comment: Based on which logic you are excluding first row for RCL?

Comment: Based on the logic of wanting to sum the max date of the RCL to the rest all other source

Comment: So for other Sources, the DayLoadDate will be always blank?

Comment: That's correct ! Thx

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new **Calculated Column** using this below **DAX** code-

```
SalesAmountsNew = 

VAR current_row_date = your_table_name[DayLoadDate]
VAR current_row_surce = your_table_name[Source]
VAR max_date = 
CALCULATE(
    MAX(your_table_name[DayLoadDate]),
    FILTER(
        ALL(your_table_name),
        your_table_name[Source] = current_row_surce
    )
)

RETURN
IF(
    max_date  = BLANK(),
    your_table_name[SalesAmounts],
    IF(
        current_row_date = max_date,
        your_table_name[SalesAmounts],
        BLANK()
    )
)
```

Now you can apply sum on that new column **SalesAmountsNew**